# no such sql table error in android

Tags: java, android, sql

I am trying to create a sql table called statescaptials and insert data from a file into it. The problem i'm getting is that when i try to query this table I get an error stating that statescapitals table does not exist. I can't figure out why

Here is my code to create the table and populate it

```
protected void populateTable()
{
    try
    {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for(int i = 0; i < states.length; i++)
        {
            cv.put("state", states[i]);
            cv.put("capital", capitals[i]);
            db.insert("statestable", null, cv);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        Log.d(tag, "populate table error");
    }


}
//************************CreateTable()*****************************    
protected void createTable() 
{
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("StatesandCapitals.db", 
             SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        db.setVersion(1);


        sqlcmd = "CREATE TABLE if not exists statestable (" +
                 "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                 "state TEXT," +
                 "capital TEXT);"; 

        scores = "CREATE TABLE if not exists scorestable (" +
                 "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                 "name TEXT," +
                 "score TEXT);";

        db.execSQL(sqlcmd);
        db.execSQL(scores);
    } 
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Log.d(tag, "table not created");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to do `USE your db;`

Comment: try a tutorial like http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html - your approach could work in the end but you're better off using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` mechanism to open & upgrade database files.

Comment: The error you mention refers to `statesandcapitals` while your code uses `statestable` - which is it?

Comment: sorry. the error is statestable. I just read an article that if i have already created a database with another table in it i will get a table does not exist error. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since i already created the database and when i try to add another table to the database i get a table does not exist error. To fix this i deleted my database and then recreated the database/tables.